# Zend OSX, and a "." added to context path

Tags: macos, zend-framework, xampp, zend-tool

I downloaded and unpacked the latest version of Zend Framework, onto OSX (10.6) (am also running webserver with XAMPP, but I added the include_path change to both XAMPP and OSX path, but this is all command line so I dont think the php compiler is using the XAMPP install)

I try to create a project and get the following:  (note that i am replacing part of the path with "----" just for the purpose of privacy)

> sh-3.2# **zf create project
>   testProject**
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend_Exception' with message 'File "Zend/Tool/Project/Context/Zf/**.**/AbstractClassFile.php" does not exist or class "Zend_Tool_Project_Context_Zf_**.**_AbstractClassFile" was not found in the file' in /Volumes/----/----/z/library/Zend/Loader.php:99 Stack trace:
>
> 0 /Volumes/----/----/z/library/Zend/Tool/Project/Context/Repository.php(88):
>   Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Tool_Proje...')
>
> 1 /Volumes/----/----/z/library/Zend/Tool/Project/Context/Repository.php(79):
>   Zend_Tool_Project_Context_Repository->addContextClass('Zend_Tool_Proje...')
>
> 2 /Volumes/----/----/z/library/Zend/Tool/Project/Provider/Abstract.php(87):
>   Zend_Tool_Project_Context_Repository->addContextsFromDirectory('/Volumes/----/...',
>   'Zend_Tool_Proje...')
>
> 3 /Volumes/----/----/z/library/Zend/Tool/Framework/Provider/Repository.php(187):
>   Zend_Tool_Project_Provider_Abstract->initialize()
>
> 4 /Volumes/----/----/z/library/Zend/Tool/Framework/Client/Abstract.php(128):
>   Zend_Tool_F in
>   /Volumes/----/----/z/library/Zend/Loader.php
>   on line 99 sh-3.2#

Note the period after "Context_Zf_"

I've narrowed it down to this block of code:

File:  /Volumes/----/----/z/library/Zend/Tool/Project/Provider/Abstract.php

```
public function initialize()
{
    // initialize the ZF Contexts (only once per php request)
    if (!self::$_isInitialized) {

        // load all base contexts ONCE
        $contextRegistry = Zend_Tool_Project_Context_Repository::getInstance();
        $contextRegistry->addContextsFromDirectory(
            dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/Context/Zf/', 'Zend_Tool_Project_Context_Zf_'
        );
        $contextRegistry->addContextsFromDirectory(
            dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/Context/Filesystem/', 'Zend_Tool_Project_Context_Filesystem_'
        );
        // determine if there are project specfic providers ONCE
```

Specifically "dirname(dirname(**FILE**))" is echoing as  "."

if I wrap the block with an 'if (dirname(dirname(__FILE))!=".") { … } ', then I don't get that error, but I get another:

> sh-3.2# zf create project testProject
>
> An Error Has Occurred
>   **Context by name applicationDirectory does not exist in the registry.**
>
> Zend Framework Command Line Console
>   Tool v1.11.3 Details for action
>   "Create" and provider "Project"
>   Project
>       zf create project path name-of-profile file-of-profile

Answer (score 0):

I tested on my Mac and it works fine. Have you tried to restart you xampp server, I don't really know how it works as I use Apache & PHP already installed versions not a "AMP pack". Maybe it's a problem with the php.ini include_path which has not been reloaded.

It's clearly a problem with the path as it don't succeed to build the class name :

```
"Zend/Tool/Project/Context/Zf/./AbstractClassFile.php"
```

the dot should not appear here.
Can you share you `PATH` variable from the terminal and your `include_path` from your php.ini.

Comment: oddly enough, I can't find the correct php.ini file to change. I have changed 5 of them now, and nothing shows a change. I am running XAMPP, but am using terminal for running the zf command. 'which php' and 'php -i | grep php.ini' both show something outside of my XAMPP install. I think the best option now is to kill xampp and maybe try to native install for Zend server.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the solution was to install zend server community edition, and have that take care of everything for me. For anyone else on OSX going this route, check out: http://cmorrell.com/webdev/installing-zend-server-zend-framework-on-os-x-291

includes the steps for enabling CLI support.